# Convert conditional summation to closed form solution

Tags: algorithm, math

Often a summation can be converted to a closed form solution.

For example

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  result += i;
```

is equivalent to `result += max(0, n * ( n - 1) / 2)`

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
    result += i;
```

is equivalent to `result += max(0, m * n * ( n - 1) / 2)`

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
    if (i < j)
      result += i;
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  for (int j=i+1;j<m;j++)
     result += i;
```

and thus equivalent to

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  if (i+1 < m)
     result += i * (m-i);
```

and thus equivalent to

```
for (int i=0;i<min(n,m-1);i++)
     result += m * i - i * i;
```

and thus finally equivalent to `result += max(0, m * min(n,m-1) * (min(n,m-1) - 1) / 2 - (min(n,m-1) - 1) * ((min(n,m-1) - 1) + 1) * (2 * (min(n,m-1) - 1) + 1) / 6)` or perhaps easier written as `result += max(0, m <= n ? m * (m-1) * ((m-1) - 1) / 2 - ((m-1) - 1) * (((m-1) - 1) + 1) * (2 * ((m-1) - 1) + 1) / 6) : m * n * (n - 1) / 2 - (n - 1) * ((n - 1) + 1) * (2 * (n - 1) + 1) / 6)`

When is such the transformation to a closed form solution possible?

It seems, if only conditions, addition and multiplication (i.e. polynomials) are allowed, it is always possible to start at the inner most loop, track the range of allowed min/max and the added polynomial.

However, doing this transformation manually, is quite error prone and time consumption, since the ranges are split at every loop and grow exponential.

Is there a tool to automatically generate the closed-form solution from the iterative version?

How much harder does it become, when division is allowed, too?

```
for (int i=2;i<n;i++)
  if (i % 2 == 0) 
    result += 1;
```

is rather easy as `for (int i=2;i<n;i+=2) result += 1;` and equivalent to `max(0, (n/2) * (n/2 + 1) )`

On the other hand

```
for (int i=2;i<n;i++)
  if (n % i == 0) 
    result += 1;
```

seems to be very hard to transform.

Answer (score 1):

While there are closed forms expressions for many sums, there are also many others, for which no one has been able to find one, like the harmonic numbers (note that the number of such sums depends on what functions you allow in the closed form).

> It seems, if only conditions, addition and multiplication (i.e. polynomials) are allowed, it is always possible to start at the inner most loop, track the range of allowed min/max and the added polynomial.

You are almost right, if the condition only affects parameters of the summation (first or last term, or possibly step size, like `if (i % 2 == 0)`), then there is always a closed form, that can be expressed as a rational function. These, among other expressions, can be computed using for example [finite calculus](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf).

For a much wider variety of expressions you can use [generating functions](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_042JS10_chap17.pdf) (see section 17.2.2 for a very gentle introduction). These can, to great extent, be used to compute closed forms for some expressions (either sums or recurrent relations).

> How much harder does it become, when division is allowed, too?

As I said, `if (i % 2 == 0)` is fairly easy, as all it does is increase the step of the sum, for example

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
  if (i % 2 == 0) 
    result += i;
```

effectively becomes

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n/2; i++)
  result += 2*i;
```

which fits well into the closed form for `n`. Other conditions, like `if (n % i == 0)` you provided, will be much harder. For example, consider very similar expression, which computes sum of the divisors

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  if (n % i == 0)
    result += i;
```

If it allowed for a closed form expression, then this could easily be used to factor numbers with two prime divisors, which is generally supposed to be hard.

Comment: So what is a good, simple tool for finite calculus? A standard CAS? But it probably could not take the C code as input